# How to Create a Series with a Range of Weeks?

Tags: python, datetime, series

I am looking to create a list of the last 6 workweeks starting from now.

What I currently have that works is:

```
import datetime
cww = datetime.datetime.now().isocalendar()[1]
cy = datetime.datetime.now().isocalendar()[0]
l6ww = [str(cy)[2:]+'WW'+str(w) for w in range(cww-5,cww+1)]

print l6ww

['18WW35', '18WW36', '18WW37', '18WW38', '18WW39', '18WW40']
```

This will work until the first WW of next year.  I can think of several brute force ways of solving this, but wanted something a bit more elegant.

Comment: Have you tried to use pandas (https://pandas.pydata.org/)? It is a powerful library that certainly does this in an elegant way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `datetime.timedelta()`:

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now().isocalendar()

l6ww = [(datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(weeks=x)).isocalendar() for x in range(6)]

final = [str(i[0])[2:] + 'WW' + str(i[1]) for i in l6ww][::-1]
```

Yields:

```
['18WW35', '18WW36', '18WW37', '18WW38', '18WW39', '18WW40']
```

This will work even as you pass into a new year, either forward x weeks or in the past x weeks. You can slightly modify this code to progress forward as well:

```
l6ww = [(datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(weeks=x)).isocalendar() for x in range(15)]

final = [str(i[0])[2:] + 'WW' + str(i[1]) for i in l6ww]
```

Yields:

```
['18WW40', '18WW41', '18WW42', '18WW43', '18WW44', '18WW45', '18WW46', '18WW47', '18WW48', '18WW49', '18WW50', '18WW51', '18WW52', '19WW1', '19WW2']
```

Comment: Brilliant.  Thank you.

Comment: That's not a bug, you can have a 53rd week in an ISO week date: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date

Comment: One minor edit.  changed str(i[1]) to str(i[1]).zfill(2).  The database I was matching uses 2 digit weeks with leading zeroes.